# Reverts on accessing concrete implementation of abstract mapping

Tags: solidity

I have two contract files A.sol and B.sol, and a test file `B.test.sol`.

Here is my current approach (reverts):

```
//A.sol

mapping (bytes32 => myStruct) public myStructs;

Struct myStruct {
  uint256 a;
  uint256 b;
  uint256 c;
}

//B.sol

interface I_A {
  function myStructs(bytes32) returns (uint, uint, uint) public;
}
contract B {
  A a;
  constructor(address a_address) { a = I_A(a) };

  function exb(bytes32 _structaddr){
    //REACHES HERE
    a.myStructs(_structaddr); //<REVERTS>
  }
}

//B.test.sol
import {A} from "./contracts/A.sol";
import {B} from "./contractsB.sol";

contract TestB {
  B testb;
  A testa;

   function beforeAll() {
     testa = new A();
     testB = new B(testa);
   }

  function test_exb() {
    b.exb();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
A a;
constructor(address a_address) { a = I_A(a) };
```

To this:

```
I_A a;
constructor(I_A a_address) { a = a_address; }
```